# Input box to change the background color of a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

On my web page I have JavaScript script that changes the background color. My HTML is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeBGC('#FFFFFF')">White</a>
```

My Javascript function is:

```
function changeBGC(color){
    document.bgColor = (color);
}
```

How can I change the color of the background getting the color from an `<input>` box instead of putting a predefined value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/X73vB/)**</kbd>

```
<input id="color" type="text" onKeyUp="color();">

function color() {
  document.body.style.background=document.getElementById('color').value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeBGC('#FFFFFF')">White</a>
```

you could have

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="inputcolorz" />
<input type="submit" onclick="changeBGC()" />
</form>
```

and for the function you could do

```
<script>
function changeBGC(){
foo = document.getElementById("inputcolorz").value
document.bgColor=(foo);
}
</script>
```

This or something along these lines should work...

Comment: I make a new html document and used this script. The page will change the color for about half a second and then revert back to white.

Answer (score 0):

The input box:

```
<input type='text' id='myinputcolor'/>
```

The Javascript:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:changeBGC(document.getElementById('myinputcolor').value)">Change Color</a>
```

Comment: When I click the text that reads the input box my page background changes to blue regardless of what I type. Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score -3):

Does this code work for you:

```html
<p align="center">
  <select name="flavorlist" size="1" onClick="javascript:document.bgColor=this.value">
    <option value="#FFFFFF" selected>Select a Background</option>
    <option value="#CCCCCC">Gray</option>
    <option value="#FF9999">Light Red</option>
    <option value="#FFCCFF">Pink</option>
    <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
  </select>
</p>
```